# Bluetooth Signal Near Power Distribution Boards

Tags: rf, bluetooth, interference

Will large currents, approximately 600 amps or more, from a power distribution panel affect Bluetooth signal range?  I would assume that the panels are designed to emit low interference but is there enough interference to still affect Bluetooth?

I don't have any means of recreating this large amperage in a lab and I typically don't deal with RF so any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Bluetooth current clamps, so I would assume it is not killing the signal.

However, the metal cabinets and wiring will interfere. An extra level of interference might be around when there are variable frequency drives near.

Answer (score -2):

Suppose the panel has, or the wiring in/out has, 600 amps with 1microsecond transitions from motor commutator spikes.

Assume the Bluetooth system has 1cm by 1cm vulnerable area, and is located 1meter from the 600 amp wiring.

What voltage gets induced into the 1cm by acm loop.

Vinduce = MU9 * MUr * Area/(2 * pi * distance) * dI/dT

Rearrange and get Vinduce = 2e-7 * Area/Distance * dI/dT

Vinduce = 2e-7 * 1cm * 1cm * 600 Million  / 1meter

Vinduce = 2e-7 * 1e-4 * 0.6Billion amp/sec = 2e-11 * 0.6e+9

Vinduce = 1.2 e-2 = 12 milliVolts

Will 12 milliVolts be a problem?

Comment: Why do you assume that whole 600A changes in 1us?

Comment: That generates a worst-case induced voltage. If that worst case is less than what would matter, we can ignore this error source? How would you model it?

Comment: I understand your point, I just say it's not a realistic worst case scenario. In distribution panel where the sum of many currents give 600A is practically impossible to have 600A/1us spike. But OP should specify the quality of that 600A current.